# Possible relation between spectra bounds of two matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, graph-theory, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

A Laplacian matrix $L\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, is a symmetric matrix with entries, \begin{equation}
l_{ij}=\begin{cases} 1=\sum_{i,~ i\neq j} w_{ij} &\mbox{if } i=j \\
-w_{ij} & \mbox{otherwise},\end{cases} 
\end{equation}
ie, off-diagonal entries, which are negative, are summing, in absolute value, to $1$ which resides on the diagonal. Note that the diagonal entries are the only positive entries. From the Gershgorin theorem it follows that the spectra of $L$ is within the range $[0, 2]$, but it is possible to obtain a tighter bound, ie, $[0, 2)$.

Now, suppose a pseudo-Laplacian $K$ is given, defined similarly as $L$, but with $w'_{ij}$ corresponding to arbitrary numbers summing, in absolute value, to diagonal entries $k_{ii}$, $\forall i$,
\begin{equation}
k_{ij}=\begin{cases} \sum_{i,~ i\neq j} w'_{ij} &\mbox{if } i=j \\
-w'_{ij} & \mbox{otherwise}.\end{cases} 
\end{equation}
So, for both $L$ and $K$, the off-diagonal entries are negative ($w_{ij}$ and $w'_{ij}$ are positive)
 Let $D=diag(K)$. Can it be shown that the spectrum of $D^{-1}K$ is within the range $[0, 2)$?

My primary intention was to derive a connection between $K$ and $L$, and to then establish spectrum equivalence. Note that for certain $L'\subset L$, $n>2$, having zero off-diagonal entries, the spectrum range includes $2$, ie, $[0, 2]$. A connection between $K$ and $L$ would therefore help establishing a bound on $D^{-1}K$, with $K$ possibly having some zero off-diagonal entries.

Comment: Hey, but $D^{-1}K$ is itself already *Laplacian*, no?

Comment: @Berci Is $D^{-1}K$ a symmetric matrix?

Comment: aand.. does the Gershgorin argument hold only for symmetric matrix?

Comment: @Berci what are the bounds? $[0,2]$, or $[0, 2)$ ?

Comment: I don't know. But.. so.. is the question you are interested in is that can $D^{-1}K$ have eigenvalue with $|\lambda|=2$?

Comment: @Berci I'm trying to get the bound $[0,2)$ on the eigevalues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that the Gerschgorin circle theorem (which is valid for any matrix, not just symmetric) states that all eigenvalues lie within the **union** of all said circles. Otherwise (if any single row described a particular bound for a particular eigenvalue) then a similarity of row scaling by $1\over n$ and the inverse column scaling by $n$ would effectively be able to tighten that bound completely to the element on the diagonal. That is effectively saying that an eigenvalue **is** the diagonal element, which of course is absurd. If such $n$ is chosen large, it may diminish the particular circle, but another circle would get larger and the union is not particularly better in the transform.